# Java Skip null object when returning with .equals()

Tags: java

I am trying out some code optimization and my current unique title validation for an object looks like this:

```
public boolean validateTitle(RawProfileConstraint rawProfileConstraint) {
    RawProfileConstraint result = profileConstraintMapper.validateTitle(rawProfileConstraint.getTitle());
    return (!rawProfileConstraint.getTitle().equals(result.getTitle()));
}
```

This works, until it throws a tantrum where the database is unable to retrieve a record that contains the title that I'm trying to validate - a.k.a it is available. `result` will be `null` in that case.
How can I incorporate a handler for `null` in this case scenario without your usual `if-else`?

Comment: Why "without your usual `if-else`"?

Comment: a ternary condition ? :P

Comment: Hint: your naming is confusing. Your validateTitle method on your "mapper" returns a RawProfileConstraint object; the  validateTitle method you are showing returns boolean. That is at least inconsistent! In my opinion, a validate method should be void and throw an exception for invalid input; or you would return some "real object" that carries meaningful information. Just returning true/false; thats almost like 1995 C-programming style. Meaning: consider renaming your methods; consider them to "work the same way".

Comment: Oh it's for a separate method that I referenced. Notice profileConstrainerMapper

`profileConstraintMapper.validateTitle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply check if `result` is null before dereferencing it:

```
return result != null
    && !rawProfileConstraint.getTitle().equals(result.getTitle());
```

or

```
return result == null
    || !rawProfileConstraint.getTitle().equals(result.getTitle());
```

depending upon what you want the result to be when `result == null` (`false` and `true` respectively).

`&&` and `||` short-circuit, so they won't evaluate the right-hand operand unless necessary:

- `false && anything == false`, so there's no need to evaluate `anything`
- `true || anything == true`, so there's no need to evaluate `anything`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was overthinking because I and could not see the overall picture properly with other things in mind. Thanks andy and ghostcat.

Answer (score 1):

One option to avoid checking for `null` is to use an `Optional` (if you are using Java 8) :

Replace

```
result.getTitle()
```

with

```
Optional.ofNullable(result).map(RawProfileConstraint::getTitle).orElse("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to step back. Why do you think that using if/else is such a bad idea?

Do you really think that a solution like

```
public boolean validateTitle(RawProfileConstraint rawProfileConstraint) {
RawProfileConstraint result = profileConstraintMapper.validateTitle(rawProfileConstraint.getTitle());
if (result == null) {
  return false;   

return (!rawProfileConstraint.getTitle().equals(result.getTitle()));
```

is so much "harder" to read than using return and && as AndyT suggested?! Or the "4 fluent statements in one expression" that Eran proposes?!

Besides: using the if like that ... also makes it clear that your have a conceptual problem with your validate method. As it seems a bit strange that a null result should cause false (or true).

Long story short: I think your code would gain the most if you would step back and re-think the "interfaces" you are using internally for your validation calls.

Answer (score 0):

[Ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) can be useful:

```
return reusult!=null?(!rawProfileConstraint.getTitle().equals(result.getTitle())):false;
```

Comment: `a ? b : false` is simply `a && b` if `b` is of boolean type. No need for the ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner for suggestion